# A problem in definite integral.

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

What will be the value of $a$ for which the integral 
$$\int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{dx}{a^{2}+(x-\frac{1}{x})^{2}} =\frac{\pi}{5050}$$

where $a^{2}\geq0$

It seems like a standard integral but $x-\frac{1}{x}$ creating all the problem.

I tried substituting $x-\frac{1}{x}=t$ and then differentiating and squaring and then rearranging but it leads us to nowhere.

I couldn't find any other substitution to solve this problem.

**Any hint will be of great help.**

Please do not provide the complete solution.

Comment: Hint: $$\int_0^\infty dx = \left(\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty\right) dx = \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{dx}{x^2} + dx\right) = \int_0^\infty dy\quad\text{ with }\quad  y = x - \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Try $x=sec \theta + tan \theta $ , not sure however
Gives $\frac{1}{x}=sec \theta - tan \theta$

Comment: @AchilleHui Can you please explain how did you get $$\left(\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty\right) dx=\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{dx}{x^2}+dx\right)$$?

Comment: just change of variable $x_{old} \to \frac{1}{x_{new}}$ for $x_{old} \in (0,1)$.

Comment: This is probably the hard way, but you could multiply top and bottom by $x^2$ and then use partial fractions.

Comment: the primitive function looks very ugly

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Achille Hui for the hint.

Adding the answer for future reference of users.

$$\int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{dx}{a^{2}+(x-\frac{1}{x})^{2}} =\frac{\pi}{5050}$$

Hint: $$\int_0^\infty dx = \left(\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty\right) dx = \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{dx}{x^2} + dx\right) = \int_0^\infty dy\quad\text{ with }\quad  y = x - \frac{1}{x}$$

Change of variable $x_{old} \to \frac{1}{x_{new}}$ for $x_{old} \in (0,1)$.

$$\int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{dx}{a^{2}+(x-\frac{1}{x})^{2}} = \int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{dy}{a^{2}+y^{2}} $$

$$\int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{dy}{a^{2}+y^{2}}= [\frac{1}{a}tan^{-1}\frac{y}{a}]^{\infty }_{0}=\frac{\pi}{2a}$$

Hence,$a=2525$.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

Set $x=\frac{e^q}{2}$ ,$dx=\frac{e^q}{2}$

It follows that 
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^q}{a^2+\sinh^2(q)}dq
$$

performing a change of variable $q\rightarrow -q'$ we see that only the numerator changes:
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-q'}}{a^2+\sinh^2(q')}dq'
$$

relabelling the dummy variable to $q$ and adding to the original integral yields:
$$
2I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^q+e^{-q}}{a^2+\sinh^2(q)}dq=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh(q)}{a^2+\sinh^2(q)}dq=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\sinh(q)}{a^2+\sinh^2(q)}=\left[\frac{\tanh(\frac{\sinh(q)}{a})}{a}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{a}
$$

And therefore
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{2a}
$$

So $a=2525$